# Silver Light RowData Bound

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am using SilverLight datagrid for showing Users Information, I have a link for opening popup window, Currently this button is showing for all records, I want to show it only if age > 18
How can I Hide the button for some records?
This is my grid

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="myDG" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="All" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" Margin="0" >
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Id}" />                        
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="0.3*"  />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Width="0.3*"  />                        
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="0.3*"  />                        
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="CREATE DATE" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding A}" Width="0.3*" />                        
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Type" Content="Hire" Margin="5,5,0,0" >
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Hire" cal:View.Model="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMResource}}">
                                                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding }" />
                                                </cal:ActionMessage>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </HyperlinkButton>                                        
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>
```

I tried by adding a variable name CanHire in my DataSource and specifying like this,but its still visible for all records

```
<HyperlinkButton Visibility="Binding CanHire">
```

Comment: What is the type of the property `CanHire`?  `bool`, `Visibility` or something else?

Comment: In that case you will need to use a converter to convert from `true`/`false` to `Visible`/`Collapsed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property CanHire is bool but Visibility is not, you can't just bind like that (and the curly braces are missing in your binding).
Try This:

```
<HyperlinkButton IsEnabled="{Binding CanHire}"/>
```

Or alternatively:

```
<someControl.Resources>
    <BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibleIfTrue"/>
</someControl.Resources>
...
<HyperlinkButton Visibility="{Binding CanHire,
        Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrue}}"/>
```

You have to implement the converter yourself or use one from a third party toolkit:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType,
                   object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```